# Use automator to make pdf look like scanned

Tags: automator, pdf

I like the idea of the site - http://lookslikescanned.com
But sometimes it doesn't work as expected.

I'd like to automator script on my Mac, so I can right click on a pdf in finder click convert to scanned ... and the output is file that looks as scanned. Preferably in the same folder just with added text on the end of the name "scanned". Like so.

[image]

To make it like this

[image]

For this I use terminal and the program ImageMagick

and here is the command line.

`convert test.pdf -colorspace gray \( +clone -blur 0x1 \) +swap -compose divide -composite -linear-stretch 5%x0% -rotate 0.5 test-scanned.pdf`

My question is how can I transfer it to automator?

**Note: the script works on images only. I'd like to use it on pdf**

Comment: When you say "looks as scanned", you mean converted into a bitmap image, rotated slightly, blurred, with a black line down each side....? 
If you've got a command line tool or scriptable app that can achieve that result, then wrapping that inside an Automator workflow is easy; but the first part is the tricky bit.

Comment: Yes. I have the first part. I posted it above. But the second is missing :D

Comment: So does your script work on PDFs or not?

Comment: Only on images my friend

Comment: This online tool works with PDFs: https://supertool.org/make-a-pdf-look-printed-and-scanned/