# How to convert a multi page pdf with text into a multi-page pdf of images?

Tags: mac, pdf, preview, image-processing

I need the PDF to look like it has been downloaded, and scanned back to be sent via email.

I therefore need a "vector" pdf with text to be converted to a multipage PDF made up of the same pages but in a raster format such as JPG etc.

I tried using ImageMagick but it seems to only be converting the first page and ignoring the rest

Comment: How exactly did you use ImageMagick, there may be just an option you are missing.

Comment: Interestingly, there is a similar question here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387876/use-automator-to-make-pdf-look-like-scanned